# Rewrite this function in Ramda

Tags: javascript, ramda.js

I was wondering if I can rewrite this function using functional style of Ramda, but how?

Can someone give some path to get this?

```
function copyProps(object, props) {
  return props.reduce(
    (acum, current) =>
      object[current] !== undefined && object[current] !== null ? { ...acum, [current]: object[current] } : acum,
    {}
  )
}
```

Example of usage:

```
user = {
  email: 'mail@example.com'
  another: 'property'
}

const result = copyProps(user, ['email', 'displayName'])

console.log(result) // { email: 'mail@example.com' }
```

Comment: If I read correctly, this is already built into Ramda as [`pick`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick), although the arguments are in the opposite order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, this is already included in Ramda as [`pick`](https://ramdajs.com/docs/#pick).

But if you wanted to roll your own, we could do this in several ways.

One would be a direct translation of your code, simply using a few Ramda functions:

```js
const copyProps = (props) => (obj) =>
  reduce ((a, p) => has (p) (obj) ? assoc (p, obj [p], a) : a, {}) (props)
```

I think this does simplify the original a bit, so it's probably useful.  But I would rather encode that conditional differently, and without resorting to `ifElse`, `cond` or other imperative-style functions.

What we really want to do is to include only those properties that are present in our source object.  Including a subset of a list is the point of `filter`, so I would rather write it like this:

```js
const copyProps = (props) => pipe (
  toPairs,
  filter (pipe (head, includes (__, props))),
  fromPairs 
)

const user = {
  email: 'mail@example.com',
  another: 'property',
  whichIs: 'skipped',
  id: 'fred',
}

console .log (
  copyProps (['email', 'displayName', 'id']) (user)
)
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.1/ramda.min.js"></script>
<script> const {pipe, toPairs, filter, head, includes, __, fromPairs} = R    </script>
```

While we could certainly find a way to make that entirely point-free, I find it pretty readable as is.